# Convert points to line

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a point shape (order number, value) which I want to convert in poliline by order of points from 1,2,3,.....x, i try in QGIS plugin Points2One but I did not succeed, can someone help me with any sugestion?

[image: Picture exemple]

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of your parameters that you are passing to the Tool in QGIS.

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop you wish to ask about in this question. I would make it match the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcMap you can use [Points To Line](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm) tool:

> Creates line features from points

Specify `Sort_Field` to create the line in desired order